# How to use PowerPivot in Excel 2013 (Home and Business)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

Is there anyway to use PowerPivot in Excel 2013 (Home and Business)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/417a711e-9747-437f-aa63-03657aacd47c/power-view-in-excel-2013-home-and-business-edition?forum=sqlreportingservices):

> Power View and PowerPivot are only available in the Office
>   Professional Plus and Office 365 Professional Plus editions. If we are
>   using office2013 Home and Business version, we will not be able to use
>   the “pro” feature of Excel like PowerPivot and PowerView.